# jQuery UI - Slider & Spinner not updating each other properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, binding, jquery-ui-slider, jquery-ui-spinner

I'm trying to bind jQuery's Slider to jQuery's Spinner, and have them both update each other and some other stuff on the page (progress bar & display output in a h1).

However my problem arises when I try to change the Slider. Since they are both changing each other, moving the Slider updates the Spinner, which in turn updates the Slider but with some strange behaviour: a kind of delay in the application of the css styling for width of fills.

I can fix the delay by commenting out

```
        // Spinner speak to range slider fill
        // $( "#rangeFill" ).css( "width", ui.value + "%");
```

but then when the user changes the spinner value, only the handle of the slider moves, but not it's fill.

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/PaulOD/2T9RU/

any help most appreciated, Thanks, Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paul, I believe your issue arises because of the way you are setting the value of your spinners when sliding.  If you move too fast when sliding the `slide` event can't keep up with you and as a result your `spinner` values get behind which causes your issues.

```
if (ui.value > last) {
    $("#spinners").spinner("stepUp", 1);
}
if (ui.value < last) {
    $("#spinners").spinner("stepDown", 1);
}
```

So update your spinners like so:

```
$("#spinners").spinner("value", ui.value);
```

Now your spinners will always keep up with the latest slider value.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/7V8Ue/)

Comment: this works really well and it's very simple, nice one Trevor. Also it fixed another issue I was having where output h1 was displaying the previous value of the spinner, now it shows the current value :)

Comment: Although the slider is working perfectly, I still had just one issue left where changing the spinner was still outputting it's previous value. I solved this by triggering the spinners change event from the spinner's button clicks. Although my solution to that part of the binding issue does not give live feedback, only when we release the button. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PaulOD/2K7bC/6/).

Comment: @Paul ahh good catch, and way to come up with a solution!  Here is another way you could do it.  http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/7V8Ue/1/ - Changed it so that the spinner is updating from the latest value, but had to add some formatting so that it showed up with the proper dollar sign and decimals. `$(".output").html("$"+ui.value.toFixed(2));`

Comment: Thanks Trevor. I developed your idea a bit: for the other currencies I used a switch statement. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PaulOD/2K7bC)